Implementing a template function to cast lambdas to function pointer with different calling convention in Visual C++
I want to create a template function that casts lambdas to function pointers of different calling conventions.
template<typename RetType, typename... Args>
auto fastcall_cast(LambdaType lambda) -> RetType(__fastcall *)(Args...)
{
    return static_cast<RetType(__fastcall *)(Args...)>(lambda);
}

int main() {
    auto pFunc = fastcall_cast([](int a, int b) -> int {
        return a + b;
    });

    // this is what I want to replicate without the boilerplate:
    auto pFunc2 = static_cast<int(__fastcall *)(int, int)>([](int a, int b) -> int {
        return a + b;
    });

};

I have been relying on this macro previously but I find it quite ugly as it requires an extra closing parenthesis in the end:
#define INLINE_HOOK(retnType, callingConv, ...) static_cast<retnType(callingConv*)(__VA_ARGS__)>([](__VA_ARGS__) [[msvc::forceinline]] -> retnType

WriteRelCall(0x4909BC, INLINE_HOOK(UInt32, __fastcall, BSAnimGroupSequence* anim)
{
    if (anim->textKeys->FindFirstByName("allowClampInLocomotion"))
        return NiControllerSequence::kCycle_Loop;
    return anim->cycleType;
}));

It is not possible to specify a calling convention directly inside a lambda in VC++ as it'll simply ignore it with a warning stating warning C4229: anachronism used: modifiers on data are ignored. Apparently you need to cast it.
Ideally the template function does not require any explicit template arguments and is able to be deduced from the lambda itself.
Is this possible in Visual C++?
EDIT: For some more context, this is for writing hooks into a game during runtime. It needs specific calling conventions so that the hooks are compatible with the game's native functions which are usually __thiscall. WriteRelCall takes the pointer value of the function, and replaces the x86 assembly in the game with the new function.
Here is the definition of WriteRelCall.
Full example of what I'm trying to do

Why do you care about calling conversations? It's none-standard extension of your platform. A pain point for every functional library. Any wrapper will eventually kill some optimization benefits. No generic solution exists yet.

@Red.Wave I am developing a mod for the video game Fallout New Vegas that requires hooking into the engine. Most hooks are into member functions that use __thiscall and __fastcall is the closest one to it that is available to use.

@JaMiT It's not, I was doing some expermination and copied the wrong code, thanks for the heads up. Still, it does not compile for the same reason.

A key factor is the template parameter pack. If you revise the template for template<typename RetType, typename Arg1, typename Arg2>, it compiles. Maybe that can helps someone find a duplicate for the error message? (I'm done searching for the day.)

I suspect that your plan to use static_cast invokes undefined behavior, since the caller and callee would be using different conventions. If you're not dead-set on casts, then Changing Calling Convention might be what you are looking for.

static_cast is well defined for msvc at least for converting lambdas into function pointers with a specified calling convention. I wasn't able to replicate the Arg1, Arg2 example as it still didn't compile. Maybe I did something wrong: https://godbolt.org/z/M16jebz91

is there something fast about fastcall?

Offtop: I think there is already a open-source  framework for FNV mods. Or it,didn't support C++11 features? Runtime version may,matter, FNV uses very old one.

@Swift-FridayPie I am probably the author/co-author of those frameworks

@korri123 "at least for converting lambdas into function pointers with a specified calling convention" -- The static_cast inside fastcall_cast does not convert a lambda. It converts a function pointer (obtained from a lambda, but that is not relevant at this point in the code). It would take quite a bit more meta-programming to pass the lambda as a parameter and apply the static_cast directly to the lambda object. Then again, if the compiler accepts the static_cast without complaint, maybe your compiler automagically adapts the calling convention.

@JaMiT Yeah that is understood. I guess the real question is how can one pass a lambda and get the type from it to be able to achieve a successful static_cast without having to add explicit template arguments to a function.

@korri123 , maybe you need to show a more concrete code snippet. The signature of the hook ing function and callbacks that it hooks are the very list I need to see. I am guessing now, that you have an XY problem.

@Red.Wave Hope this explains it better: https://godbolt.org/z/E18oEr7Yr

@korri123 all I see in the compiler explorer is you trying to emulate assembly. I don't see any API functions that demand specific calling convention. There is the "windows.h" header that could contain relevant declarations, but I don't see your code using any. So I ask again: what specific library function are you calling, and what is the type of the callback it needs as arguments?

@Red.Wave I am not calling any library that expects any calling convention, I am hooking and patching a compiled video game's assembly with my own functions, and those functions need to match the calling conventions of the game.

So you're trying to overwrite SB else's binary code at runtime, while also optimizing for runtime? It looks more like a hack. I could understand it if it was own or open sourcecode;  you wouldn't need calling conversations in that scenario.

@Red.Wave You are not stating anything that wasn't already obvious to me. I am fully aware that what I'm doing is considered unorthodox in the normal C++ world but that is not relevant to the original question, which was asking if there was a way to convert a lambda parameter from a template function to a function pointer with a different calling convention (which to be fair, probably wouldn't be required in any other case than mine).

Optimized code is the thing that you probably can't get. But The behavior can be emulated. If all the inputs are trivial, or reference, optimized code is possible on MSVC, otherwise you need GCC. When ask for wierd things, patience is the prime requirement.

That's fair, apologies for sounding aggressive.

I'm a bit busy now, and the question needs a bit more thoughts. I should keep you waiting. But I still need to know if copy/move on arguments is acceptable or optimized behavior is needed. Optimized behavior may be not achieveable.

@Red.Wave Depends on compiler. Plus in that environment if I recall right compler gt a flag to define default call conventions. Windows got that problem that they have  entire toolbox of calling conventions available, not just one. I'm kind of curious what this project is, it's not NVSE?

@Swift-FridayPie almost all compiler have calling conversations. They even provide similar ones for same structures, but std is agnostic about them. And compilers are really inconsistent about calling conventions. They make developer's life miserable.

@Swift-FridayPie It's xNVSE (updated NVSE), yep. But I'm using this in a different project of mine called kNVSE which is a plugin for it.

Wit MSVC x86 target, first we need an arg forwarder different from std::forward:
template<typename targ>
[[msvc::intrinsic]]
constexpr decltype(auto) fast_fwd(std::type_identity_t<targ>& arg){
    /*if constexpr(std::is_reference_v<targ>
          or not std::is_trivial_v<targ>)
        return static_cast<targ&&>(varg);
    else*/ 
        return static_cast<targ>(varg);
};

This forwarder captures trivial arguments by value. On second thought, it should be a simple static cast. But the abstraction allows for later tweaks.
Next a detail only dirty template function:
template<auto lambda, typename R, typename ...A>
R __fastcall as_fast_impl(A ...v){
    return lambda(fast_fwd<A>(v)...);
};

Now a declare template variable with usless implementation:
template<auto lambda, typename fptr = decltype(+lambda)>
constexpr auto as_fast = nullptr;

Next specialize the real use case:
template<auto lambda, typename R, typename ...A>
auto constexpr as_fast<lambda, R(*)(A...)> = as_fast_impl<lambda, R, A...>;

The cast is ready. We can make fastcall pointers out of empty capture lambdas
auto fast_call_ptr = as_fast<
[](int,int)->int{
    return 0;
}>;

This is a C++20/C++23 solution. Aside from typos in my snippet, due to a now-resolved defect in std wording, some combinations compiler version and std version setting may reject lambda as NTTP. Otherwise, the code tries to optimize away copy/move of argument; but in general, if arguments are none trivial and none reference, copy/moves will be inferred into the fastcall wrapper. Moreover the lambda needs to have single none-generic (no [](auto...)), none-template(no []<A...>) function call operator.

This is the correct answer, verified in Godbolt that it works (had to fix a few typos in fast_fwd like the missing colon in the attribute and return type). Kudos, this is some C++ magic I've never seen before.

decltype(auto) is the universal return type. I had a pre-recorded talk on functions in meetingcpp.com 2years ago. I was planning for another on function type-traits ar cppcon, but I had to cancel . These are always at the back of my mind.

You don't need an explicit cast to convert a (non-capturing) lambda into a function pointer.  The compiler can do that conversion implicitly for you when you assign the lambda to the pointer. Let it figure out the calling convention for you, eg:
int (__fastcall *pFunc)(int, int) = [](int a, int b) -> int { ... };
// or:
// int (__fastcall *pFunc)(int, int);
// pFunc = [](int a, int b) -> int { ... };

template <typename RetType, typename... Args>
void WriteRelCall(UInt32 jumpSrc, RetType (__fastcall *jumpTgt)(Args...))
{
    ...
}

WriteRelCall(0x4909BC, [](BSAnimGroupSequence* anim) -> UInt32 { ... });

See: how to specify vc11 lambda calling convention
If, for some reason, you do need an explicit conversion, you can simply use the unary + operator, eg:
+[](int a, int b) -> int { ... };

+[](BSAnimGroupSequence* anim) -> UInt32 { ... }


If you pass the lambda as an rvalue like in the latter example, and WriteRelCall writes the pointer value of the function as a hook somewhere in the binary, I'd assume it'd always be compiled with cdecl calling convention, right?

I wasn’t aware you could use the unary + operator on function pointers - but I imagine that’s because this is such a niche use case. Are there other scenarios where this would come up?

@templatetypedef A positive lambda: +[]{} - What sorcery is this?

@korri123 the lambda takes on whatever calling convention is used by the function pointer it is assigned to. Behind the scenes, the compiler can implement a separate operator() overload for each calling convention used.

@RemyLebeau That's something I understand, but in regards to my question the goal is to avoid manually writing the function pointer definition and assigning to it manually. The goal is, for fastcall_cast to deduce the return type and arguments from the lambda and generate a function pointer from it with __fastcall as a calling convention.

@korri123 What is the actual signature of WriteRelCall()? The lambda takes on the calling convention of the function pointer it is assigned to. If you are having trouble with that, then it sounds like you are not actually using function pointers correctly.

@korri123 "The goal is, ..." - sorry, that will not work. AFAIK, you can't detect the return type and arguments of a lambda, so you'll need the conversion before creating your wrapper. Even if you could detect them, you can't convert the lambda to a function pointer and then type-cast it into another function pointer with a different calling convention. When the "function" is called, you risk corrupting the call stack, or crashing the code, as the caller and callee will expect different things. What you need is a separate __fastcall wrapper that invokes the target lambda the right way.

@RemyLebeau This should give you a bit more context: https://godbolt.org/z/EY13habno

@RemyLebeau a wrapper sounds like an okay solution if the compiler will inline it but seems like a inferior solution to the INLINE_HOOK macro which converts the lambda directly to a fastcall function. By the way, I have updated the question so there's less confusion about what I want to do.

Full context is here: https://godbolt.org/z/E18oEr7Yr

@korri123 Why not simply write an overload of WriteRelCall() that takes a __fastcall function pointer as a parameter, and then pass a lambda to it?

@RemyLebeau I thought about that and I think it'd share the same issues as the fastcall_cast function no? I'd probably have to write a new overload for every game function that has a different signature (i.e. return type or arguments). Unless there is some generic way to pass any type of fastcall function?

Make the WriteRelCall template on function pointer argument and use lambdas with +. The lambda needs empty-capture list and single callable operator(generic or template lambdas can not compile). Invocation: WriteRelCall(where_to, +[](int){});

@korri123 your godbolt example is compiling for 64bit. You do know that calling conventions like __fastcall and __thiscall only exist in 32bit, don't you? There is only 1 calling convention in 64bit, and it is dictated by the 64bit API. There is no language keyword for the 64bit calling convention, and the other conventions are simply ignored by a 64bit compiler for backwards compatibility with 32bit code.

@RemyLebeau All of the godbolt examples I posted are on msvc x86-32 and not x64. You can verify it even further by looking at the assembly which is using 32 bit registers in the side window. Even if I would make the mistake of picking the incorrect compiler, why do you feel the need to lecture me about that?

@korri123 When I looked at your godbolt links earlier, they were set to 64bit, now they are set to 32bit, odd.

@Red.Wave I think if you use the unary plus operator on the lambda the function will default to cdecl. I think I'm at terms now that this isn't possible since you can't extract the argument types of a lambda using metaprogramming afaik. I'll stick to the macro.

@RemyLebeau I feel like I'm being treated as some C++ idiot here rather than people trusting my judgement or thinking about the question. Why would I be asking it if I didn't know anything about calling conventions?

@korri123 I'm not calling you an idiot. I don't know you, how would I possibly know your experience? I was merely stating a coding fact. Sorry for saying anything. I'm done with this discussion. I posted my answer, accept it or ignore it as you wish.

It's fine, I guess text can sometimes be perceived as condescending when that is not the intention. Apologies for the misunderstanding.

On x85 this probably don't compile. __fastcall is not convertible to __cdecl. But I guess, I have cooked sth. Wait a bit.
